# Textarea scrollHeight always has minimum two rows worth of height?

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<textarea>` that grows and shrinks to fit the size of the input, using the element's `scrollHeight.` For the most part this works fine, growing or shrinking to fit the amount of intput within the textarea, but with one exception.

When there's only a single row of text within the textarea, the scrollHeight still gives two rows worth of height.

Is there anything I can do to make it shrink to one row of height when only one row of content is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use row attribute on the textarea tag. It will set the row height

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting this?

CSS:

```
textarea {
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="1"><textarea>
```